# <option> value to <input> text value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select

I am trying to set a input box's value and text from a select element.

```
var p = document.getElementById("pretestNameSelect");
var test = p.options[p.selectedIndex].value;
if (choice.toString() == "type0")
{
    alert(test);
    $(document.getElementById("type0")).show();
    hideOtherQuestionDivs(choice.toString());        
    $(document.getElementById("pretestNameSelectHiddenTextQ0")).value = "test";
    $(document.getElementById("pretestNameSelectHiddenTextQ0")).text = "test";
    alert(document.getElementById("pretestNameSelectHiddenTextQ0").value);
}
```

The alert(test) works and shows the correct value but the value is not set and the alert(doc...) shows an empty alert.

What could be the problem?

Comment: What does function `$` look like? If you have jQuery, your code does not make any sense. jQuery input field values are set by `$(selector).val(value)` and gotten by `$(selector).val()`

Comment: Is that all of the code?

Comment: Why are you mixing jQuery selectors (`$()`) with vanilla javascript selectors (`getElementById()`) ?  Use one or the other.

Comment: Perhaps you meant `var $p = $("#pretestNameSelect");
var test = $p.val(); 
if (test == "type0") {

    $("#type0").show();
    hideOtherQuestionDivs(test);        
    $("#pretestNameSelectHiddenTextQ0").val(test);
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing Jquery Selectors with DOM selectors.

You can use

```
$('#pretestNameSelectHiddenTextQ0').val(test);
```

or

```
document.getElementById('pretestNameSelectHiddenTextQ0').value = test;
```

Comment: Thats the problem when you dont have enough reputation to comment :D

Comment: You are welcome and now you have enough rep so well done :)